# How to add <script> tag in ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

I am trying to add a script tag in ckeditor (source mode) but after adding the tag it converts to the invalid tag. I am try to change config.js file like this

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.allowedContent = {
    script: true,
    $1: {
        // This will set the default set of elements
        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
        attributes: true,
        styles: true,
        classes: true
    }
};

};
```

and I am also trying to like this bbcode, example [script][/script]
How can I add script tag in cfeditor?